# Z3 SMT Solver - How can I extract the value of a floating point number in FPA?

Tags: c++, floating-point, z3

I am using Z3-4.6.0 C/C++ API on linux machine.

I am stuck in a very stupid problem. I have a solver in QF_FP logic, and the solver is able to return SAT for the input problem.

When I do

```
  z3::model model = z3_solver_.get_model();
```

I get

```
(define-fun var_1 () (_ FloatingPoint 11 53)
(fp #b0 #b10000000001 #x3333333333333))
```

Then call eval

```
z3::expr r = model.eval(z3::expr(var_expr), true);
```

and I get

```
(fp #b0 #b10000000001 #x3333333333333)
```

I know the answer is correct as I checked it through the IEEE-754 converters online.

But I cannot seem to figure out/find out any function which will return this value to me. Is there any built-in function like **Z3_get_numeral_uint64 (...)** which returns a real value, or even if it returns numerator and denominator separately, that also works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(fp #...)` *is* the value/numeral as defined by the SMT FloatingPoint theory. It is precise and avoids any problems that come with rounding and/or truncated real-numbered expressions. E.g. converting this value into a `double` would require at least one rounding and converting a float with a large exponent to decimal-real representation may be huge.

You can use the `Z3_fpa_get_numeral_*` functions to extract separate sign, significand, and exponent values as bit-vectors, strings, or int64s, but it is up to the application to combine and/or approximate them.

Further, there is the parameter called `pp.fp_real_literals` to enable real/decimal numbered representations for model values, which `Z3_get_numeral_string` should respect. Those are also split into significand and exponent, but they may ease debugging.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Z3_get_numeral_string returns the model values split into significand and exponent, like you said. Of course, I will have to combine then myself otherwise the built-in functions lost precision which I don't want.

Comment: Update: At least I can view the correct number by setting the precision of std:cout. So, all good! :D

Comment: JFS has code for taking a triple of bitvectors and turning them into a floating point type. It only does this for Float32 and Float64 though. Here's the code which you might find useful.
https://github.com/delcypher/jfs/blob/4cb90edfc3ea89ce5477a15a4102d7f3bb5bdb61/runtime/SMTLIB/SMTLIB/NativeFloat.cpp#L666